# CDI Keeps all Injected tree references of SessionScoped beans?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-7, weld

I am starting a new project with JavaEE 7 and declared a Sessionscoped bean to maintain the web logged user information in session.

The `UserSessionBean`, as I named it, is intended to be lightweight - trying to avoid lots of data to be kept in the session by Weld. But in some cases I need to get all user information, so added a `getUser()` method which must query and retrieve a `UserEntity` from JPA. In order for the method to do its job, I need to `@Inject` other resources onto the `UserSessionBean`.

My question is: These dependant resources will be kept and serialised within the `UserSessionBean` by Weld until the context is destroyed?

The weld documentation says this:

> An instance of a dependent bean is never shared between different
>   clients or different injection points. It is strictly a dependent
>   object of some other object. It is instantiated when the object it
>   belongs to is created, and destroyed when the object it belongs to is
>   destroyed.

That makes me think the all `SessionBean` tree is kept by weld during session life, but how can I keep a lightweight `SessionBean` and use injected CDI resources on it?

Comment: If the dependent resources are not kept there what would happen with them when UserSessionBean gets deserialized?

Comment: It could be reinjected by container on deserialization.

Comment: Where should the container store your dependent object until your UserSessionBean gets deserialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you're injecting are also CDI beans, it is not the beans themselves that get serialised, but their *lightweight* proxies. Upon deserialisation, the proxies dynamically resolve the correct beans for whatever scope they are. See section **5.4 Client Proxies** of the [CDI1.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/web_beans-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/web_beans-1_0-fr-spec.pdf). Hence, your bean is as lightweight as possible.

Comment: I'll read the spec to better understand these proxies. Thank you!